HOW using Postfix as MTA. My mail server connects as unknown on Postfix and is disconnected instantly
I'm trying to connect a Communigate mail server and use Postfix as MTA.
Only when the Communigate server tries to connect to Postfix, I get this message which appears in a loop in the logs:
Dec 27 09:11:16 fx1 postfix/smtpd[44553]: connect from unknown[172.20.0.143]
Dec 27 09:11:16 fx1 postfix/smtpd[44553]: disconnect from unknown[172.20.0.143] quit=1 commands=1

My Communigate server is configured to send emails to Postfix via port 30587. And when I run my mail sending script, I get this error message displayed:
root@cg1:~ # sh send_email.sh
554 5.5.0 Error: SMTP protocol synchronization

When I execute this command on this port, it notices that it is a service managed by the postfix server fx1.test-mail.net:
root@cg1:~ # nc localhost 30587 
220 fx1.test-mail.net ESMTP Postfix

and when I run these commands following the previous netcat I get this result:
HELO  
250 2.0.0 Ok
MAIL FROM:<demo@domaine.fr>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<demo2@domaine.fr>
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Subject: Test Mail
From: test@domain.com
To: recipient@domain.com

This is a test email.
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 85C8147AD2

The mail goes through the postfix server, but is never delivered, and there is always this connection and disconnection problem
What could be causing the problem? I tried to look through the log and configuration files, but I found absolutely nothing

It can be anything. We need to know much more about your setup to even start guessing things. That said, why do you want to do this? CommuniGate includes its own MTA, as far as I remember.

Tell us about the DNS records that you created
